# display javascript inside html?

Tags: javascript, html

hi all im new to javascript and can't for the life of me get this to display in html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <body>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/category.js"></script>
       <select><script>
        var makeModel = new DynamicOptionList("MAKE","MODEL","TYPE");
    makeModel.addDependentFields("MAKE2","MODEL2","TYPE2");

    makeModel.forValue("Ford").addOptions("Fiesta","Focus","Taurus"); // Add options if VALUE of option is selected
    makeModel.forText("Honda").addOptions("Civic","Accord","Prelude"); // Add these options if TEXT of option is selected

    makeModel.forValue("Ford").setDefaultOptions("Fiesta");
    makeModel.forText("Honda").setDefaultOptions("Accord");
    makeModel.forValue("Ford").forValue("Taurus").addOptions("2-door","4-door");

    makeModel.forField("MODEL").setValues("Focus","Taurus");
    makeModel.forField("TYPE").setValues("2-door");
    makeModel.forField("MODEL2").setValues("Civic","Prelude");

    makeModel.forValue("Toyota").addOptionsTextValue("Camry","10-CAMRY","Corolla","20-COROLLA","Celica","30-CELICA"); // Add options with values different from text
</script></select>
</body></head></html>
```

code from http://www.mattkruse.com/javascript/dynamicoptionlist/ example 3

Comment: Java **is not javascript**

Comment: Java and Javascript are like apples and apple-bottom jeans, like grenades and sting grenades - same only by name.

Comment: Did you include the right JavaScript library in your html file?

Comment: thanks for clearing that up for me. but can anyone help me out with this

Comment: yes i have the library include in the html " <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/category.js"></script>"

Comment: is this a eazy thing to do or am i just missing something

Answer (score 0):

at the first, you should know that, JavaScript is completely separate from Java!
so, by the way, if you want to write some JavaScript code inside html, you should use script tag inside your `<body></body>` tag like the example below:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> // your javascript code here! </script>
```

as an option, you can add external JavaScript file, and attach it to your script tag like example below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="example.js"></script>
```

for more information, check out [this place](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_howto.asp).

Answer (score 0):

The example you refer to makes use of an additional library called DynamicOptionList.js that you can find [here](http://www.mattkruse.com/javascript/dynamicoptionlist/source.html).

According to [the documentation](http://www.mattkruse.com/javascript/dynamicoptionlist/) you also need to initialize the library by calling initDynamicOptionLists() in the `BODY` onLoad attribute (or from somewhere else).

Comment: i have that thanks just cant get the scroll box with the info to show

Comment: not really as i don't know how to do that some code would help me out alot

Comment: just letting you know i don't know javascript at all